# Does the Steel Charge mod affect the damage of Ash's Bladestorm ability?

Tags: warframe

Since Ash's blade storm damage is affected by power strength and melee combo multiplier, and I heard somewhere steel charge counts towards the combo multiplier, so I'm wondering does steel charge affect the damage of blade storm?

Also, I know its pretty unlikely, but do the mods that increase melee damage(ie.Pressure Point) affect the damage of blade storm?

I'm just trying to maximize the damage output of blade storm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steel charge now increases Ash's Blade Storm damage.

As of 7/15/2015's [Hotfix 16.11.5](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/490942-hotfix-16115/) patch:

> - Ash’s Blade Storm is now affected by the Steel Charge Aura Mod.